# Executing robocopy using Powershell 2.0 command line is doing nothing. No errors

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am newbie to Powershell and Robocopy.
I am trying to run Robocopy command from Powershell 2.0 command-line nothing is happening no error messages.

But when I execute the same command using the Windows cmd-line it works fine. 
The command details are as follows

```
   $src="\\Test1\"
   $dest="\\Test2\"
   robocopy $src $dest /V /E /R=0 /W=0
```

I tried this also

```
   robocopy \\Test1\ \\Test2\ /V /E /R=0 /W=0
```

My system is Windows 7 professional. The same script also works when executed using the Sapian powershell studio.

Am I missing anything here?

Any help in this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://serverfault.com/questions/129098/how-to-get-robocopy-running-in-powershell

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
robocopy $src $dest "/V" "/E" "/R:0" "/W:0"
```